# Download TXT file from URL and save to PC on Flutter Web

Tags: download, flutter-web

I have a problem with my project, I wanna to download a `.txt` file and save to any directory with Flutter WEB, I think I put the setup but It does not work. Now de `.txt` file display the content in the same tab of browser, but I want to download this file, here is my code:

```dart
void downloadFile(String url) {
    html.AnchorElement anchorElement = new html.AnchorElement(href: url);
    anchorElement.download = "plantilla_simulador.txt";
    anchorElement.dispatchEvent(html.Event.eventType('MouseEvent', 'click'));
    anchorElement.style.display = 'none';
    anchorElement.click();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to download file from another site.
Keep in mind that [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes) only works for [same-origin URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), or the `blob:` and `data:` schemes.

This code should download file:

```
html.AnchorElement(href: 'index.html')
  ..download = 'some_name.txt'
  ..style.display = 'none'
  ..click();
```

but this one should open file in browser:

```
html.AnchorElement(href: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/flutter/master/flutter_console.bat')
  ..download = 'some_name.txt'
  ..style.display = 'none'
  ..click();
```